# Gibt es auch eine deutsche Version von Standard eBooks?

Tags: book

Gibt es eine ähnlich Initiative wie [Standard eBooks](https://standardebooks.org) auch für deutsche Bücher?

Standard eBooks ist ein Projekt in dem freizugängliche Texte (z.B. [Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org)) typographisch überarbeitet werden.

Comment: Manche Buchhändler bieten online kostenlose ebooks an, zum Beispiel https://www.ebook.de/de/category/59011/gratis_ebooks.html Meistens sind das Bücher, deren Copyright abgelaufen ist (wie bei Sherlock Holmes). Diese Bücher sind überarbeitet und modernisiert (Cover, Schriftbild). Andere Bücher sind Leseproben.

Comment: Geht es um die Überarbeitung? Denn als EBook hat Projekt Gutenberg sie ja selbst: https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Category:DE_B%C3%BCcherregal

Comment: Genau @Janka mir geht‘s um typografisch ‚schöne‘ eBooks. Standard eBooks gibt sich hier sehr viel Mühe und verbessert die Ausgaben kontinuierlich.

Comment: Ich kenne keine Initiative, aber man kann das (wirklich schöne) Format von Standard eBooks ja auch für deutsche Bücher verwenden - der Quellecode ist ja einsehbar. Es müssen sich halt Leute finden, die sich hinsetzen und sich die Mühe machen ...

Comment: stimmt, vor dem 'Selbermachen' steht aber erstmal das Umarbeiten der Stilvorlage (z.B. Anführungszeichen). Freiwillige?

Comment: gibt es da Freiwillige, so was in Deutsch zu machen? Ich bin aus der IT, aber alleine würde ich das nicht machen wollen.

Comment: Ich wäre dabei.

Comment: Es stimmt natürlich immer froh Projekte zu sehen, die sich für eine schöne Typographie einsetzen, doch ob es dafür eines besonderen Projektes bedarf? Ich nutze als Referenz (deutsche Typographie) gerne die Reihe von Marion Neubauer: [Mikrotypographie-Regeln](https://www.dante.de/tex/Dokumente/dtk-neubauer.pdf)

Comment: @Janka Gutenberg mag deutsche Bücher haben, es hat aber keine Bücher mehr für Deutsche: "Visiting from a German Internet address? As of February 27 2018, addresses in Germany are blocked."

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not a perfect match, but the [Deutsches Textarchiv](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/) publishes a lot of free works whose copyright has expired under a free licence. They are focussed on corpus linguisitics and use TEI as their main publication format, not one of the ebook standards.

*Auf Deutsch:* Das ist vielleicht nicht genau das Gesuchte, aber das [Deutsche Textarchiv](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/) publiziert viele historische Texte, deren Copyright abgelaufen ist. Sie bieten ihre Text im TEI-Format zum Herunterladen an, aber nicht als E-Books.

Comment: Warum antwortet ein deutscher Muttersprachler wie du auf eine Frage in einem Deutsch-Forum, die in fehlerfreiem Deutsch gestellt wurde, und zwar von jemandem der in Deutschland lebt, in einer anderen Sprache als Deutsch?

Comment: Ich bin vorher in einem anderen Stackexchange unterwegs gewesen und habe nicht in der Sprache umgeschaltet ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android , Google play Books is an app which stores information about the digitally published books. You can get German version of published eBooks from there if available.

Answer (score -1):

Nein, bis jetzt gibt es keine Initiative.

Comment: Eine Quelle für die Aussage wäre nicht schlecht.